# Command mvn test seems not find JUnit5 parameterized test

Tags: java, maven, junit5, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm trying to execute my JUnit5 tests on Maven with the command `mvn test`. I've added maven-surefire-plugin on the pom like this:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                    <version>5.5.2</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

My tests are implemented in four classes, named:

```
IOTest.java
OperationTest.java
TaskTest.java
UtilityTest.java
```

The tests are correctly executed from Eclipse but when I run them from shell with `mvn test` only the ones annotated with `@Test` are executed, while those annotated with `@ParameterizedTest` seem not visible.

Comment: Adding the dependency to the plugin is wrong. Add the dependency to your code with scope test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you are missing the scope, try adding scope in the dependency as shown below

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I've already added `junit-jupiter-api` dependency with scope test to the dependencies. Adding also `junit-jupiter-engine` the result is the same.

Comment: have you added - <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>

Comment: This is what i've missed! Thank you!